# A parasite template?

Tags: pdftex, texmaker, biography

Recently I want to write a biography. So, I get (just copy paste) the template from Overleaf. Then, I realize that every archive .tex that I compiled and run in texmaker always have output (pdf) the biography template that I copied previously. So, if I run every archive at my pc sure this will soon "destroy" all my files. I also give you my drive link to see the **.log** file , hoping that someone knows better and help me. Thanks.

Link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Glw9G99DH_h017V33ow1BCoIvMYorZb2

Comment: How should we know from a log file? And why are you ignoring errors? That log mentions many many errors

Comment: The truth of the matter is that everything was ok before I Just create a file of my biography. Then everything's ruined. I don't know how?Is that possible?? Tell me what can I give you to makes you understand the problem.

Comment: start with fixing the first error `! LaTeX Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands.` you have two  `\documentclass` lines so latex can not produce any reasonable output at all.

Comment: that error is completely unrelated to anything you mention in your question..  running  latex will never destroy your files, it never writes to the source files at all,

Answer (score 2):

Your log file shows

```
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/marvosym/marvosym.sty

! LaTeX Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.25 \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{
                                       moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12..
```

Which seems to imply that you have over-written the file

`c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/marvosym/marvosym.sty`

which should be a latex package file with a document using the `moderncv` class.

You need to restore `marvosym.sty`

`tlmgr --reinstall marvosym`

might be enough, depending how much of texlive you over-wrote previously